# scroll button text - android

Tags: android, button, scroll

I want to enable scroll in the button when the text is too long. Can I do it?
This not work (and I understand why), but there is a sultion?

```
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/question_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/readingText"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/question"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_with_frame"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: put Button in linear layout

Comment: you want to scroll the text that is displayed on button?